# Possible to compare date strings in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that contains documents with a date attribute like so:

```
{
   title: "whatever",
   created: ISODate("2013-05-27T03:36:50Z")
}
```

I would like to select records that were created on a certain day.  I was hoping I could use `toDateString()` and compare the values but when I do a search like the one below:

db.myCollection.find({ 'created.toDateString()': new Date('05/27/2013').toDateString() }).pretty()

But this does not work.  Is there any way to do what I am attempting above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select records then use a date range:

```js
db.collection.find({
    created: { "$gte": new Date("2013-05-27"), "$lt": new Date("2013-05-28") }
})
```

And that selects all the contained hours, minutes etc, falling between the two dates.

So you **should** be trying to use the date values and not coerce into strings.

If you want this for doing aggregation or otherwise **need** the results in a day only format then do this using [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and the date [operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Still match on the normal date forms, this time whole month
    { "$match": {
        created: { 
           "$gte": new Date("2013-05-01"), 
           "$lt": new Date("2013-05-31") 
        }
    }},

    // Project the date
    { "$project": {
        "date": {
            "year"  : { "$year"  : "$created" },
            "month" : { "$month" : "$created" },
            "day":  : { "$dayOfMonth": "$created" }
        },
        "title": 1
    }},

    // Group on day and title
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "date"  : "$date",
            "title" : "$title"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Sort by date
    { "$sort": { 
        "_id.date.year": 1,
        "_id.date.month": 1,
        "_id.date.day": 1,
    }},

    // Project nicer dates and document
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "date": { "$concat": [
            { "$substr": [ "$_id.date.year", 0, 4 ] },
            "-",
            { "$substr": [ "$_id.date.month", 0, 2 ] },
            "-",
            { "$substr": [ "$_id.date.day", 0, 2 ] }
        ]},
        "title": "$_id.title",
        "count": 1
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Neil. Can I ask why I "...should be trying to use the date values and not coerce into strings"?

Comment: @AbeMiessler it's generally not a good idea because there is a cost involved in the coercion. What you were attempting with find would not work, unless using $where, and that would **force** a table scan, as well as slowing down for executed JavaScript. Finally it is not necessary as shown in both examples. The only valid case is for a final projection, but there is no reason why you cannot do that part in code. Always use dates.

Comment: Thanks for this! There's a small typo FYI - two colons after the day field in the date projection.